# how to give dataadaptor in jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have created a .jrxml file using iReport eclipse plugin. It takes json as an input. I have created jsonDataAdaptor inside the eclipse to export the report. Now I want to do the same using java, not iReport.

I have a .jrxml file and i am compiling the file using:
    JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile

In the .jrxml file I have created some fields for the json and have used in textField.

```
 <field name="username" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[username]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="pwd" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[pwd]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
```

I am having the username and pwd's in the test.json that is placed in my local drive in the same path as the .jrxml file.

My dataAdapter(in the same folder as .jrxml file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<jsonDataAdapter class="net.sf.jasperreports.data.json.JsonDataAdapterImpl">
<name>jsonDataAdaptor</name>
<fileName>C:\test\test.json</fileName>
<useConnection>false</useConnection>
<timeZone xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    dirty="false" DSTSavings="0" raw-offset="19800000"
    xsi:type="java:sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo">
    <ID>Asia/Calcutta</ID>
    <display-name>India Standard Time</display-name>
</timeZone>
<locale country="US" language="en" />
<selectExpression></selectExpression>
<datePattern></datePattern>
<numberPattern></numberPattern>
</jsonDataAdapter>
```

The problem is, when I am exporting the same into html I am getting values as null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [link](http://krams915.blogspot.in/2010/12/spring-3-mvc-jasper-integration.html) for jasper datasource adapter.